# Owning or sharing a resource between objects

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, c++17

A have a collection of worker objects with the following type:

```
template<class T> struct Worker;
```

Different workers, having different template arguments `T`, use some resource

```
struct Resource;
```

`Resource`s used by different `Worker`s all have the same type but possibly different values. Resources are heavy in general, unnecessary copies should be avoided. Resources are used only by workers, some are used exclusively, some are shared between them (this information is available at compile-time). If a resource is used exclusively, I want a `Worker` to be (possibly, effectively) the owner of it, otherwise it should store a reference. In pseudo-code, I want to do either

```
Resource resource1(...);
Worker<Type1> worker1(..., std::move(resource1));
// worker1 owns resource1

Resource resource2(...);
Worker<Type2> worker2(..., std::move(resource2));
// worker2 owns resource2
```

or

```
Resource resource(...);
Worker<Type1> worker1(..., resource);
Worker<Type2> worker2(..., resource);
// workers use resource, but do not own it
```

I see two direct ways to do it:

1. Use a template parameter to determine the type of the data member in `Worker` that represents a resource:

   ```
   template<class T, class R>
   struct Worker
   {
       Worker(T arg, R resource) :
           resource_(std::forward<R>(resource))
       { }  

       R resource_;
   };

   template<class T, class R>
   Worker(T arg, R&& resource) -> Worker<T, R>;

   void foo()
   {
       Resource r;

       Worker worker1(0, r);
       Worker worker2(0, r);
       // type of worker1.resource_ is Resource&,
       // type of worker2.resource_ is Resource&,
       // both store a reference to r

       Worker worker3(0, Resource{});
       // type of worker3.resource_ is Resource,
       // Resource{} is moved into it
   }
   ```
2. Use `std::shared_ptr`:

   ```
   template<class T>
   struct Worker
   {
       Worker(T arg, const std::shared_ptr<Resource>& resource) :
           resource_(resource)
       { }

       template<class R, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<R, Resource>>>
       Worker(T arg, R&& resource) :
           resource_(std::make_shared<Resource>(std::move(resource)))
       { }

       std::shared_ptr<Resource> resource_;
   };

   void foo()
   {
       auto resource = std::make_shared<Resource>();

       Worker worker1(0, resource);
       Worker worker2(0, resource);
       // worker1 and worker2 share *resource_

       Worker worker3(0, Resource{});
       // worker3 effectively owns *resource_
   }
   ```

These approaches are obviously very different but are effectively equivalent in present case. I don't like them both.

In the first case I don't like that the resource is stored outside `Worker`s in some local variable. There is a potential risk to get a dangling reference in the `Worker`.

In the second case unnecessary counted reference remains in `resource` after all `Worker`s have been created. I could take `shared_ptr` by value and use `std::move` in the last `Worker` construction, but it would require me to track the last constructor explicitly - an excellent way to get a bug.

These concerns do not influence the correctness of the code, but probably signify that the whole design is flawed. I think there should be much better approach. Please explain what are the best practices in such cases. (I understand that my question may be too generic, and the solution I need may depend on the exact way I create resources and workers; good solution may result from a different view on the problem, and currently I'm stuck in the two approaches I outlines above.)

[Full code here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7c199504b8990d96).

Comment: Is the workers lifetime related to each other in any way? Are they possibly managed by a single object, etc.? I think, that the way you decide to share the resources, should greatly depend on that. E.g. if all workers are managed by a single object (so they lifetimes are bound to that object), you should probably let the object manage their resources as well, and pass only references to resources for the workers to work on. On the other hand, if you don't know anything about the lifetime relations between the workers, you should probably go for std::share_ptr instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In the second case unnecessary counted reference remains in resource
>   after all Workers have been created. I could take `shared_ptr` by value
>   and use `std::move` in the last Worker construction, but it would
>   require me to track the last constructor explicitly - an excellent way
>   to get a bug.

No, you don't; Create your resources with `unique_ptr` by default, it costs "nothing" to convert it to a `shared_ptr` when needed.

---

Consider using only a constructor that takes a `std::shared_ptr` *by value*;
`std::shared_ptr` has a constructor that takes an *rvalue* `std::unique_ptr`;

```
template<class T>
struct Worker
{
    Worker(T arg, std::shared_ptr<Resource> resource) :
        resource_(std::move(resource))
    { }

    std::shared_ptr<Resource> resource_;
};

void foo()
{
    auto resource = std::make_unique<Resource>();
    auto resource_shared = std::make_shared<Resource>();

    Worker worker1(0, std::move(resource));
    Worker worker2(0, resource_shared);
    Worker worker3(0, resource_shared);
    // worker2 and worker3 share *shared_resource


    Worker worker4(0, std::move(resource));  //resource is empty
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c5002e906073e420)

Comment: My point was that until a local variable `resource_shared` is destroyed, it adds one to the reference counter. I can move from it, but only in the last `Worker` constructor.